# counterfactual prediction in country-year data

Tags: predictive-models, count-data, counterfactuals

I'm trying to explain a time-varying country-year count variable of an event (Y) with both time-varying and time-variant variables (X); I have data of a around 100 countries for 20 years (2000-2020). I'm running a negative binomial regression with random country intercepts; corresponding to the R formula `Y ~ X1 + X2 + Xn + (1 | country)`.

My understanding of the coefficients of X is that they contain both within and between country variation.

I'm being told that interpreting coefficients is not illustrative enough.

I thought a illustrative way of showing the impact of the explanatory variables would be to hold each individually at their values at the beginning of the observation period, predict Y from this modified data, and attribute the change in Y to the change in X (e.g. if X1 had stayed at its 2000 level, 50 Y less would have taken place in the countries included in the dataset, while if X2 had stayed at 2000 levels, 30 Y more would have taken place).

Is this procedure permissible and this interpretation correct? In particularly since my coefficients contain both within and between country variation, I'm wondering if predicting Y from X1 values held constant at 2000 will impose between-country variation on a within-country process.